# Comparing the strenght and weakness of multiple factor calculation

Tags: java, performance

**Here is an exam question**. It tells me to Comment on the strengths and weakness of each implementation, using the criteria of correctness,design, efficiency, and readability.**(i.e, doing error checking and if there is any improvement can be made? )**

Question:

The methods foo1 and foo2 are intended to calculate the number of positive
factors of a positive integer. For example, the six factors of 12 are 1, 2, 3, 4,
6, and 12, so foo1(12) or foo2(12) should return 6.

```
private int foo1(int n) {
2 for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
3 if (n % i = 0) {
4 return i;
5 }
6 }
7 }
8
9
10 public int foo2(int n) {
11 int count = 1;
12 for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
13 if (n % i == 0) {
14 count = count + 1;
15 }
16 }
17 return count
```

**My anwser to the question :**
foo1 has higher efficiency  as it does not need to repeat a calculation eveyrtime. 
Yet Foo1 has syntax in error in lane3 where 
if (n % i = 0) should be if (n % i == 0); 
Moreover, the  return of foo1 for input argument "12" will be 12 rather than the expected "6"  ; 
Also, the return statement in foo1 in incompleted, "return 1" should be added outside the for loop.
Lastly, if the method is private, it cannot be used by another class.

**Any other suggestion? Is my thought thorough enough?**

Thanks

Comment: For starters, `foo1` has a bug in it.  Second, there's no need to include line numbers.  Third, these methods are doing two entirely different things (provided the bug in `foo1` is missing an extra `=`).  Fourth, what is it specifically that you're asking?

Comment: `foo1` is littered with errors. `return i;` is an error too, it simply doesn't work as described. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @Makoto umm. It is an exam question it asks me to comment the errors , efficiency and possible improvement of the two given methods. I post my thought to let others check if it is correct.

Comment: @Radiodef I think the method is private making it impossible to be used in another class as well.Do you agree?

Comment: That's not a requirement of the design so I don't care to speculate.

Comment: Other bugs: the return statement in `foo2` is missing a semicolon, the `foo2` method is missing a closing curly brace.

Answer (score -1):

My Implemention:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Factor {

    public static List<Integer> foo1(int n) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(1);
        for(int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
            if(n%i == 0) {
                list.add(i);
                list.add(n/i);
            }
        }
        list.add(n);
        list.sort(new Comparator<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
        });
        return list;
    }

    public static int foo2(int n) {
        int count = 2;
        for(int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
            if(n%i == 0) {
                count+=2;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 12;
        for(Integer i: foo1(n)) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        System.out.println(foo2(n));
    }

}
```